# Why is the germinal library not shadowing configuration?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm in the process of writing some characterisation tests for [germinal](https://github.com/jfmcbrayer/germinal), prior to adding functionality. To do this, I'd prefer to use a `let` form and temporarily shadow configuration than setq it.

However, this doesn't work the way I expected it to, for some of the configuration.  `*germinal-host*` can be shadowed, but the certificate configuration `*germinal-cert*` can't:

```
CL-USER> (let ((germinal:*germinal-cert* "/foo/bar"))
           (print germinal:*germinal-cert*)
           (germinal:start :background nil))

"/foo/bar" ;; Germinal listening on 0.0.0.0 port 1965
gemini-handler error: SSL initialization error: Can't load certificate /etc/germinal/cert.pem
SSL error queue is empty.
```

Am I missing the correct way of configuring the germinal client during tests?  I could just globally `setq` the values I want, but I'd like the config to be overridden only during tests, hence use of `let`.

Comment: Okay I think I get it.  All configuration special variables are shadowed - for example, both `*germinal-host*` and `*germinal-cert*`.  However, the reason the former 'works' is that it's used in the context it's shadowed in - at creation time of the server.  However, `usocket` is using its own context - *not the context in which the special variables are shadowed* - to handle the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some [smart folks on the usocket-devel mailing list](https://mailman.common-lisp.net/pipermail/usocket-devel/2021-December/000640.html), I have the answer: restructure the germinal server to add a helper function that returns a closure, closing over the shadowed variables.  This closure then has the correct variable values regardless of which thread invokes it:

```
(defun make-gemini-handler (cert cert-key root-path)
  "Create a Gemini request handler for a specified root path, TLS certificate, and TLS key."
  (lambda (stream) (gemini-handler stream cert cert-key root-path)))
```

This is invoked from the main thread like so:

```
  (with-global-context (*germinal-tls-context* :auto-free-p (not background))
    (usocket:socket-server host port (make-gemini-handler *germinal-cert* *germinal-cert-key* *germinal-root*) ()
               :multi-threading t
               :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)
               :in-new-thread background)))
```